# Get all subscription groups and product ids from itunes connect

Tags: javascript, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I want to get all subscription groups (with product ids) in itunes connect from my backend side. I am looking at the documentation but I can not find any endpoint for that.

I mean, something similar to google which you can specify the packageName and it returns all product ids:

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts/get

```
this.androidpublisher.inappproducts.list({
        auth: this.authClient,
        packageName: packageName
      },
```

Does Apple provide an endpoint for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be done from within your app with an [SKProductsRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproductsrequest?language=objc). The products could be different based on the user's country (availability, pricing, etc.).

It may be easier to just store a hardcoded mapping of your `product IDs -> data` on your server.

Comment: That is what we are currently doing (using a google spreadsheet with all products Ids, countries, prices, etc) but it is not the best solution and requires someone to update the spreadsheet every time we add new products Ids, etc, etc.

Comment: Yup. It's not the best solution but Apple doesn't provide an endpoint for it.

Comment: I asked it in the itunes dev forum as well: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/116082
and although the answer doesn't come from someone from Itunes, it is clear that Itunes doesn't provide any server to server endpoint for this.